# The number of both IS / ARE

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which of the following sentences are correct?

1. The number of both cars and motorcycles **is** ten.
2. The number of both cars and motorcycles **are** ten.

I think the first one, since the noun is "the number", but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you surmise, the number **is**, regardless of how many items are involved.